# vba - sending email from a different user

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

My client wants to distribute excel/vba to his clients and the vba will automatically send emails.

Maybe the sender should be some other account, not the outlook account of the person using the vba, because some private stuff might be in the email. Is it really possible?

Another thing is the infamous pop-up warning when automating such tasks. I heard Application.SendKeys doesn't always work when computer's locked.

How is CDO for this task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send email from Excel in Exchange environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122747/send-email-from-excel-in-exchange-environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your initial question you can use `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` with Outlook

On the Security warning the standard two solutions for Outlook are:
1) Use [Clickyes](http://www.contextmagic.com/express-clickyes/)
2) Install [Outlook Redemption](http://dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm)

Comment: + 1 :) There is a 3rd option. Reduce the security in Outlook. I have done that and I don't get those popups any more (I am using Off-2010)

Comment: @SiddharthRout As long as you are aware this is not recommended.

Comment: @JP: Yup on a shared PC it is definitely not recommended. But on my personal laptop which one one else has access + It is fully protected with Latest AV software + I am careful not to open any unknown macro files, I don't see any problems :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Outlook to send emails. As you ask, CDO works without using Outlook.

Here's some code to get you started.

```
Public Sub SendEmail(Subject As String, Body As String, ToPerson as String)

Dim iCfg As Object
Dim iMsg As Object

Set iCfg = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

With iCfg.Fields
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "email-account"
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendemailaddress") = "account@domain.com"
   .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
   .Update
End With

With iMsg
   .Configuration = iCfg
   .Subject = Subject
   .TextBody = Body
   .To = ToPerson
   .Send
End With

Set iMsg = Nothing
Set iCfg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I no longer have the original source. This is code I use in one of my projects.